# How can I get particular fields from a shopify gem api query

Tags: ruby, shopify

I want to only return certain fields in query.

For example:

```
ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:all,:params=>{:resource => "products"},:fields=>['value'])
```

I only want to return the value field from the metafield object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came close. You forgot to actually provide an ID for a resource. In your case, since you're looking for all the values of the metafields assigned to a product, you need to provide the product ID.

```
ShopifyAPI::Metafield.all(params: {resource: 'products', resource_id: 149523945, fields: 'value'})
=> [
  #<ShopifyAPI::Metafield:0x007f80041f3958 @attributes={"value"=>"4999"}, @prefix_options={:resource=>"products", :resource_id=>149523945}, @persisted=true>, 
  #<ShopifyAPI::Metafield:0x007f80041f36b0 @attributes={"value"=>"Céà"}, @prefix_options={:resource=>"products", :resource_id=>149523945}, @persisted=true>, 
  #<ShopifyAPI::Metafield:0x007f80041f3408 @attributes={"value"=>"Cíao"}, @prefix_options={:resource=>"products", :resource_id=>149523945}, @persisted=true>, 
  #<ShopifyAPI::Metafield:0x007f80041f3160 @attributes={"value"=>"1"}, @prefix_options={:resource=>"products", :resource_id=>149523945}, @persisted=true>
]
```